# Is it allowed to download and use Microsoft Aerial imagery in research papers?

Tags: bing-maps, satellite-image

I was wondering if it is allowed to download and use (i.e. I mean processing not just displaying) Microsoft Aerial imagery in research papers? Is there any reference clearly mentioning the use of these data for research purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this would fall under the print rights: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/product/print-rights

Generally, using screenshots in research papers of an application with Bing Maps is not usually an issue. Just be sure the copyright information is clearly displayed.